# Including remote java script return by service in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, recaptcha

I have a web service that returns java script.  The service is basically a wrapper around Google captcha service. It works simply including it in html code like following.

```html
<body>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://host/captchaservice/generate.htm?userName=me">
      </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The service returns output which looks like this

```
var scripts=[]; scripts.push('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en'); for(src in scripts) document.writeln('<scri'+'pt src="'+scripts[src]+'" type="text/javascript"></sc'+'ript>') document.writeln('<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="12341234234asdf324f324rf34t23f341234"></div>')
```

Now I need to incude this captcha service in my JSF page.

- using `<h:outputscript>` you can only include local scripts
- using it in separate script by using JQuery get call and use eval() on    returned data does not work.
- Also need to paste it in exact location.
- -I can try using it in backing bean, but at the end I have to format the    script in an html control.

There should be an easy way to do this which I am not probably aware of. BTW, I am using JSF 2.0.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: using <verbatim> works but not sure I can access the param from managed bean, keep you posted.

Comment: What exactly is your problem when just using `<script>` tag exactly as shown in your first code snippet?

Comment: I thought <script> wont work in JSFwhen I used it initially I had some issue. It turns out I had some issue with passing keys and nothing to do with <script> tag. I tried bare <script> again after you suggested, and it took it. Thanks.

Comment: JSF is just a HTML code generator. The webbrowser -the HTML retriever/interpreter- absolutely doesn't care who/what/how the HTML generates.

Comment: Now that the captcha script showing google captcha link, I am having hard time retrieving value. It is simply fetched by calling
'request.getParameter("g-recaptcha-response");' in JSP. In JSF I should be able to fetch it using FacesContext  like following:

        'Map<String, String> parameterMap = (Map<String, String>)context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String val = parameterMap.get("g-recaptcha-response");'